# Magical string is set to SPRING_CONFIG_NAME when it is deployed to docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

After deploying my spring boot application to Docker, when I run `set` command on the terminal I see some magical string is set to spring_config_name as

`SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=/78d0a2ab-2744-4a78-a294-ab33e26bbf40/spring-config-1`

Also there are many additional spring specific properties set by default. 
Due to this, my application.yml is not getting loaded. For now I am able to load it by externally specifying  `SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=application` on the command line.

Comment: Post your docker-compose and Dockerfile

Comment: I think I found the answer. In docker we can link to other docker containers. In my case, my web application is linked to spring cloud config container. This linking created those environment variables. So either we can avoid linking container directly and just use spring cloud in the traditional way or just pass an argument to the spring boot in command line `spring.config.name=application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. In docker we can link to other docker containers. In my case, my web application is linked to spring cloud config container. This linking created those environment variables. So either we can avoid linking container directly and just use spring cloud in the traditional way or just pass an argument to the spring boot in command line `spring.config.name=application`